# Should I install debug tools?

Tags: debug

I've been a long time user of Ubuntu (Warty)
Now I wonder if I should install debug tools for various installed software?
I don't really understand how they work; for instance (have to be activated or work in the back ground and pickup errors or crashes) Do they need set up or direction?  I have mostly let apport do reporting so far.
Thanks

Comment: Only if you are going to debug the program yourself - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/ and http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `*-dbg` packages unless you want to investigate abnormal program terminations, in which case debugging information for the involved executable binaries may be of great help in tracking down the cause of the problem. Even if you don't do the investigation yourself, you can submit the generated reports to other people to inspect (e. g. on a bug tracker).